# Java Swing InputEvent modifiers for various hardware

Tags: java, swing, keyboard-shortcuts

I am looking for a list of (hardware) modifier keys and their mapping to masks in the Java Swing interface `InputEvent`.  As Java 7, there are five masks I know about:

- `SHIFT_DOWN_MASK`
- `CTRL_DOWN_MASK`
- `META_DOWN_MASK`

  - See [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_key).
- `ALT_DOWN_MASK`
- `ALT_GRAPH_DOWN_MASK`

  - See: [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key).

Please kindly draw my attention if I am missing any.

[From this Eclipse bug report about SWT](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=55236), I learned:

- Apple machines tend to have four keys: <kbd>command</kbd>, <kbd>option</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd> and <kbd>control</kbd>.
- PC-style machines tend to have five keys (nowadays): <kbd>control</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>win</kbd>, 
  and <kbd>menu</kbd>.

  - For this discussion, I do not consider the <kbd>menu</kbd> key a modifier.  (Again: Correct me if wrong.)
  - However, <kbd>win</kbd> key can be used in combination, e.g., <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to open a new window for Windows Explorer.

I realize the line between "PC" and "Apple" has blurred in the past few years.  It may be possible to have keyboards with a plethora of modifiers.

My questions:

1. How does the Apple <kbd>command</kbd> and <kbd>option</kbd> keys map to `InputEvent` masks?
2. How does the PC <kbd>win</kbd> key map to `InputEvent` masks?

Comment: AWTEventListener returns all Key & Mouse Events in Integer form, have to test before if KeyBindings implemented in Swing API to consume() those events and then those events aren't longer accesible for AWTEventListener, KeyListener, everything depends of if Key Event are used together with MosueEvent, then there are a few bugs in Java7 APIs(in compare with Java6), never need to solve that somehow, only to know that there are bugs betweens documentations and events fired from ....

Comment: [This (admittedly old) Apple page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/07-NativePlatformIntegration/NativePlatformIntegration.html) says Java's Meta is equivalent to a Mac's Command key, while Java's Alt is equivalent to the Option key.

Answer (score 4):

"Shortcut" or "Accelerator" keys are easily handled in a cross- platform way
in Swing.

The Toolkit gives the key ID for the native OS shortcut key:

```
int shortcut = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ().getMenuShortcutKeyMask();
```

With this you can make a KeyStroke

```
    int key = KeyEvent.VK_Q; // or whatever
    KeyStroke ks = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke( key, shortcut );
```

The method getMenuShortcutKeyMask is the correct, cross-platform, Sun- supported way of obtaining the appropriate modifier mask for menu accelerators (AKA shortcuts) for the current platform. It returns a modifier mask using the appropriate java.awt.event.InputEvent constants for the current platform -- on OS X this is InputEvent.META_MASK, on Windows it is InputEvent.CTRL_MASK. Using these literals instead of calling getMenuShortcutKeyMask is bad form, although it works.

One additional thing to note is that you can use combinations of modifiers in accelerator keystrokes:

```
KeyStroke ks = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke( KeyEvent.VK_P, shortcut | InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK );
```

to create a Command+Shift+P keystroke (on OS X, Control+Shift+P on Windows). This allows you to create accelerator keystrokes using mnemonic keys that are used by standard menu items (e.g. Print, which uses Command+P) without conflicting with the standard keystrokes.

In the case of Windows key:

```
// Invoked when a key has been pressed.
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    // Returns the integer code for the key on the keyboard and if
    // keyCode is equal to VK_WINDOWS)...
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS) {
        // ...call the doIT method.
        doIT();
    }
}
```